# How do I use one table that shows relationships between two or more tables by looping over each row as I do a select statement?

Tags: sql-server

Say this table name is `Template` and I want to create tables for Company1, Company2, etc using a dynamic query and the relationship displayed below.

| ID | Schema | YearTablesNames | ColumnsInYearTables | QuarterTableName | ColumnsInQuarterTables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company1 | Year | **ID** | Quarter | **ID** |
| 2 | Company1 | Year | ColumnA | Quarter | ColA |
| 3 | Company1 | Year | ColumnB | Quarter | ColB |
| 4 | Company2 | Year | ID | Quarter | ID |
| 5 | Company2 | Year | ColumnA | Quarter | ColA |
| 6 | Company2 | Year | ColumnB | Quarter | ColB |

An example using the above template. I want to loop over each distinct schema and create a table using the following result set

Iteration #1:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Company1Test
FROM
{
    SELECT 
        a.ID, a.ColumnA,
        b.ColA
        CASE  
            WHEN a.ColumnA = b.ColA THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
        END Test1
        a.ColumnB,
        b.ColB,
        CASE 
            WHEN a.ColumnB = b.ColB THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
        END Test2
    FROM 
        Comapany1.Year a
    JOIN 
        Company1.Quarter b ON a.ID = b.ID
} f
```

| ID | ColumnA | ColA | Test1 | ColumnB | ColB | Test2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 12 | TRUE | 13 | 14 | FALSE |
| 2 | 800 | 900 | FALSE | 13 | 14 | FALSE |
| 3 | 12 | 12 | TRUE | 99 | 890 | FALSE |

And then iteration #2:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Company2Test
FROM
{
    SELECT 
        a.ID, a.ColumnA,
        b.ColA
        CASE 
            WHEN a.ColumnA = b.ColA THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
        END Test1
        a.ColumnB,
        b.ColB,
        CASE 
            WHEN a.ColumnB = b.ColB THEN 'TRUE' 
            ELSE 'FALSE' 
        END Test2
    FROM 
        Comapany2.Year a
    JOIN 
        Company2.Quarter b ON a.ID = b.ID
} f
```

| ID | ColumnA | ColA | Test1 | ColumnB | ColB | Test2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 300 | TRUE | 456 | 14 | FALSE |
| 2 | 800 | 900 | FALSE | 13 | 14 | FALSE |
| 3 | 125 | 125 | TRUE | 99 | 100 | FALSE |

Comment: This honestly feels like the real problem is the design, and you are using multiple tables where you should be using 1.

Comment: I am testing data from different datasets

Comment: Essentially I am trying to develop one script that will cater for anything that will be added to the template as and when need. I want to have one master table to only amend and not 100 stored procedures for 100 companies. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, check out how cursors work in sql server and start coding your loops, the end result should be the SQL you generated in the question

Comment: I think there's no need to tell you that you shouldn't be doing this :D Read about "Inner platform effect". PLus, your design is not flexible, since you don't know which columns should go to JOIN, and which should go to select

Comment: *"Essentially I am trying to develop one script that will cater for anything that will be added to the template as and when need."* This sounds like a terrible idea. Design your tables for your needs. Don't design tables to tell you what tables to use.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out and let you kou know how it goes